# Accessing Amazon RDS Oracle database from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, oracle, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2013

I have set up an Oracle database on Amazon RDS and am attempting to build an asp.net webpage to access it. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have the AWS Toolkit installed. I'm able to see my database instance in the AWS Explorer and can even modify it but I'm not able to add the database to the server explorer so I can utilize it from a webpage project.

If I right click on the database instance in the AWS Explorer and choose 'Add to Server Explorer...' nothing happens. When I open the DB Instances window and right click on the database the 'Add to Server Explorer...' option is greyed out.

I did try setting up a SQL Server database and was able to connect to that so I think it must be something specific about Oracle. I installed ODAC and it didn't help. I would be very appreciative for any advice you could offer.

Thank you.

Comment: Also check you have allowed the sql net traffic in/out on the Amazon server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an Oracle database to Server Explorer without the proper tools. Each database vendor provides different management capabilities and APIs. Server Explorer works with SQL Server out of the box because it already includes the proper integration provider.

You can download [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) from Oracle's site.